# JOIN  выборка с несоответствующим id из родственных таблиц?

Tags: база-данных, php, запрос, sql, mysql

Из таблицы `T2`, нужно посчитать сумму `sum(field)`, где связь с таблицей `T1` осуществляется по полю `rel_id = T1.id`, бок в том что `T2.rel_id` может быть = 0, но эту запись тоже нужно засчитать, как это сделать?

```
SELECT sum(field) FROM T2
JOIN T1
ON T1.id=T2.rel_id
```

*запрос как запрос, но еще раз объясню, нужно засчитать и ту запись, поле `rel_id` которой равно именно 0, а не NULL или еще чему-либо, даже если такого id такой записи нет в таблице T1*

Возможно ли это?

Comment: немного уточните:
нужно засчитать ту запись, поле rel_id которой равно 0, даже если такого id такой записи нет в таблице T1 , но не защитывать другие rel_id если такой записи нет в таблице T1?

Comment: засчитывать другие!

Answer (score 1):

Да, left join

Comment: увы, не захватывает.

Comment: Не верю. Попробуйте:
SELECT sum(field) FROM T2
left JOIN T1
ON T1.id=T2.rel_id
where rel_id = 0
Только предварительно убедитесь, что у вас действительно есть строки с rel_id = 0

Comment: вернуло 2, это нормально, значит есть такие поля.

Comment: Мой запрос вернул 2?
и вы хотите сказать, что при этом запросы "SELECT sum(field) FROM T2
JOIN T1
ON T1.id=T2.rel_id" и "SELECT sum(field) FROM T2 left JOIN T1 ON T1.id=T2.rel_id" у вас выдают одинаковые результаты?
Если да, это может означать только одно - в t1 у вас есть строка с id = 0.

Comment: Ладно, спасибо за помощь. У меня другие мысли появились просто. Ситуация такая что лучше даже запросы разделить средствами php. Так что извиняюсь что побеспокоил.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT sum(field) FROM T2
LEFT JOIN T1
ON (T1.id=T2.rel_id)AND(T2.rel_id=0)
```

Comment: Так должно засчитывать? Если да, то вы правы.